# Building GNU Development tools: freshly obtained BINUTILS and GDB source trees seem to be outdated

Tags: cross-compiling, gnu, binutils

I am using [these instructions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/simtest-howto.html) to build cross GNU tools.

After I obtained the sources and tried building them (for `frv-elf-uclinux` but that does not matter too much) using provided steps I found out by searching for error messages which I got that at least two patches (I wanted to link them but not enough rep yet) are not applied, both are quite old, and I then found out that changelogs residing in corresponding folders are dated from 2013 year while ChangeLogs from different folders are more recent.

Given that those instructions were the only official pages those I could find, I cannot think out anything better than to ask a question on SO. How do I obtain the missing fresh sources to build cross GNU apart from downloading every part (GDB, binutils, simulator etc) one by one?

Comment: Or, should I say "GCC" instead of "GNU"?

Comment: Binutils and GDB are more GNU than GCC, so your choice of words is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

those insns look correct -- the latest binutils tree is available from that git repo, and the latest gcc tree is available from that svn repo.  you're going to have to outline the exact files you're looking at for more help.

you can also check `git log` in the binutils tree to see what the latest commit is, or `svn log` in the gcc tree.  they'll both include dates.